# Shell script “dvc pull” not working at Streamlit server

Tags: python, bash, streamlit, dvc

In my Streamlit app.py file, I used the code `os.system("dvc pull")` to load a .csv data file (`labeled_projects.csv`) from my Google service account (Google Drive), and it has been working well since I deployed it a few months ago. The code itself is loaded from my GitHub account.

But it appears that the code suddenly stopped working and I got the error message `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mount/src/mlops/data/labeled_projects.csv'`.

The Streamlit server provides no error message regarding the execution of `os.system("dvc pull")`.

Attempting to replace `os.system("dvc pull")` by using the `tempfile` package to create a .sh file and executing it using the `subprocess` package does not help. Got the same `FileNotFoundError` message with no error message about `dvc pull`.

Also, executing the command `find . -name 'labeled_projects.csv'` at the streamlit server could not find any matching return, which seems to indicate that the file is not downloaded.

The code `dvc pull` in the Stremlit app.py file works fine if executed locally.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Tony. DVC maintainer here, could you please create an issue in https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues and provide verbose log for the error (add -v flag) and `dvc doctor` output, please? I'm not 100% sure, but you might be affected by a bug we recently fixed, in which case one-time `rm -rf /var/tmp/dvc` might fix it for you. If it does not - let's continue in github and investigate it further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @pmrowla and @ruslan-kuprieiev for the feedback.

First I updated the `dvc` to version 3.14.0. Then I found out that, one issue in my case is in fact, with a simple Shell script of `dvc pull` within the Streamlit `app.py` file, the correct executable of `dvc` that is installed into the Streamlit server from the `requirements.txt` file can not be successfully reached.

In the following, I just quote the answer I got from ChatGPT 4 for your information. The code in the quote resolved my problem and the `.csv` data file from my Google Drive was successfully loaded.

(start quote) "To run `dvc pull` (or any other command that requires a Python package installed in the virtual environment) within a Streamlit app deployed on Streamlit sharing, you'll need to take several steps.

1. **Install the Required Packages**:
   Ensure you have `dvc` listed in your `requirements.txt` file in your GitHub repository. When you deploy the app on Streamlit sharing, it will automatically install the packages listed in `requirements.txt`.
2. **Use Python's `sys.executable`**:
   You can use Python's `sys.executable` to get the path to the Python interpreter. This will help ensure you're calling the right Python environment where `dvc` is installed.
3. **Run the Command from Python**:
   Use `subprocess` to run the `dvc pull` command from within your Streamlit app.

Here's an example:

```py
import sys
import subprocess
import streamlit as st

def pull_data_with_dvc():
    cmd = [sys.executable, "-m", "dvc", "pull"]
    result = subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True, text=True)
    if result.returncode == 0:
        st.write("Data pulled successfully!")
        st.write(result.stdout)
    else:
        st.write("Error pulling data!")
        st.write(result.stderr)

# Use this function somewhere in your Streamlit app.
pull_data_with_dvc()
```

Remember:

- Ensure you've set up your DVC remote correctly.
- If DVC requires authentication, you'll need to provide the necessary credentials, which might be more involved, especially if you want to keep credentials secure.
- This method assumes that DVC is installed as a Python module (as opposed to a standalone system binary).

Lastly, note that Streamlit sharing has some limitations in terms of storage and resources. If you're pulling a large amount of data, you might hit those limits. Always review Streamlit's documentation and limitations for the latest details." (end quote)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using DVC 3.x, it's likely this bug, which is fixed in the latest release (`3.14.0`): https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues/9651

Once you have updated DVC to the latest release, you may also need to clear the DVC site_cache_dir. If you run `dvc doctor` on your server you will see output like:

```
DVC version: 3.14.0 (pip)
---------------------------------------------
Platform: Python 3.11.4 on macOS-13.5-arm64-arm-64bit
Subprojects:
    ...
Supports:
    ...
Config:
    ...
Cache types: reflink, hardlink, symlink
Cache directory: apfs on /dev/disk3s1s1
Caches: local
Remotes: https
Workspace directory: apfs on /dev/disk3s1s1
Repo: dvc, git
Repo.site_cache_dir: /Library/Caches/dvc/repo/73fbe43150218852364cf8d86e2a305f
```

To clear the cache, you can simply remove the directory listed in the `Repo.site_cache_dir` line (the last line in `dvc doctor` output) like:

```
rm -r /Library/Caches/dvc/repo/...
```

(on linux the path will probably be in `/var/tmp/dvc/...`)

It is also safe to just remove the entire `/var/tmp/dvc/...` directory as well if you are unable to determine the specific `repo/...` path for your app instance on the server (this will clear the cache for all DVC repos located on the server)